# Why segment fault in recursion in C

Tags: c, quicksort

I have the following piece of C code for implementing quick sort algorithm by myself.

```
unsigned int mid_pos = FIND_MID(start, end);
unsigned int piv_pos;

/* Medium of three partitioning pivot picking */
if ((data[start] <= data[mid_pos] && data[mid_pos] <= data[end]) || 
        (data[mid_pos] >= data[end] && data[mid_pos] <= data[start]))
    piv_pos = mid_pos;
else
{
    if ((data[start] <= data[end] && data[mid_pos] >= data[end]) ||
        (data[start] >= data[end] && data[mid_pos] <= data[end]))
        piv_pos = end;
    else if ((data[start] <= data[end] && data[start] >= data[mid_pos]) ||
            (data[start] <= data[mid_pos] && data[start] >= data[end]))
        piv_pos = start;
    else
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        piv_pos = rand() % (end - start) + start;
    }
}

pivot = data[piv_pos];

while (i < j)
{
    while (data[i] < pivot)
        i++;
    while (data[j] > pivot)
        j--;
    if (i < j)
    {
        swap(&data[i], &data[j]);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

/* recursion */
quick_sort(data, start, j);
quick_sort(data, i, end);
```

For 1 set of test case (1M numbers) it hangs. Not so sure about why.

---

I have found the problem, the testing data set was not good if use median of three algorithm. I changed the pivot picking to completely random and it was OK then.

```
unsigned int piv_pos = rand() % (end - start) + start;
pivot = data[piv_pos];
```

Comment: What prevents you from adding a complete log of the given data in your implementation?

Comment: Because I don't have the input data itself. I can only compile with that .o file which contains `main()` function, where all the data are there.

Comment: Yes you have it, your quick_sort implementation receives it, or does it not?

Comment: Yes it does. And it has over 1M numbers.

Comment: @hlx98007 Then you `printf()` the parameters inside your quicksort function that it receives.

Comment: Hi, I am not asking how I could print out the passed down `*data` 1 by 1, because yes I can get that but I won't be able to post the data here on stackoverflow (1 million numbers). I am asking if there is a memory access violation or other kind of error that can cause segment fault based on this piece of code.

Comment: Ok, well then I guess your previous comment stating that you did not have the input data was invalid. Attach a debugger to your program and you shall see the segfault in action.

Comment: My bad. I did not explain clearly enough.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Some environments are easier to debug than others. If you are using an OS which gives you a core file when you get a segmentation fault that core file can be used to quickly pinpoint the problem. You might have to enable core dump by allowing a limit at the shell prompt, something like:

ulimit -c 500000
(in bash)

or:

limit coredumpsize 500M
(in tcsh)

Assuming that your program was compiled with debug flag and without too much optimization you can easily pinpoint the problem with something like:

ddd myprogram core

Ddd is a graphical debugger, you could also use gdb if you feel familiar with that command line debugger.

Another very useful tool to pinpoint problems like this is valgrind, example:

valgrind myprogram

Valgrind might give warnings about uninitialized memory or memory leaks. It might also suggest some options to give more warnings.

However, which tools you have depends very much on your OS and installed programs. Valgrind and ddd are both Linux programs.